# Stackdriver cannot get inventory list and apache data other than scoreboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-stackdriver

I'm working on a project where I have several GCE instances serving web content through apache.

I've installed stacdriver monitoring and logging successfully in those instances, but in the Resources -> Apache HTTP server stackdriver view, the inventory does not get populated (loading data eternaly) and in the right side the only thing that started showing up under APACHE tab after installing the agent is the Apache Scoreboard. It does not show active connections, workers, etc.

Strange thing is that if I ssh in to the instances and wget a status page, I can see all the metrics.

I've been trying to solve this issue, but I cannot find any info that points me in the right direction!

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled the [plugin](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/apache#enabling_the_apache_monitoring_plugin)? it seems that this could be caused by the agent not running correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by enabling the plug-in?

Comment: Luke, yes, I've configured the plugin as mentioned in the link you provided. That's why I can get the scoreboard, but not the other metrics (connections, traffic, etc). That's the weird thing! Furthermore, if I ssh into the VM's and issue a CURL I get this:

Comment: `curl http://local-stackdriver-agent.stackdriver.com:80/server-status?auto
Total Accesses: 15685
Total kBytes: 18363
CPULoad: .0021476`
Uptime: 712890
ReqPerSec: .022002
BytesPerSec: 26.3767
BytesPerReq: 1198.83
BusyWorkers: 1
IdleWorkers: 9
Scoreboard: ________W.._....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................`

Comment: You don't have all the same metrics as for other applications or resources, this is the [list of metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-apache) so make sure that the ones listed under there if not create a [public issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for the stackdriver team.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'll open  public issue.